# Как узнать все пути до строки кода?

Tags: python, c++, c, поиск-программ

Существуют ли инструменты, с помощью которых можно узнать все возможные пути (стеки/трэйсы) до какой-либо строки кода?

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но, думаю, в общем случае он не решаемый. Ведь ветвление кода может зависеть от данных, а какие будут данные на момент исполнения кода - да кто его знает. А там могут быть и циклы ещё, и вызовы функций друг из друга.

Comment: А что означает "все пути". Если перед строкой if..elif..else, то сколько тут путей? А если внутри ещё цикл?

Comment: Многие профайлеры показывают стеки вызова приводящие к заданной строке. (Например, vtune, но думаю не только она.) Но, именно по результатам выполнения, а не все потенциальные стеки.

Comment: Статический анализ не может решить эту проблему, из-за [проблемы остановки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8). На практике профайлеры собирают такую информацию для конкретных данных на входе программы.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio - Контекстное меню для функции -> View call hierarchy

Clion - Главное меню -> Navigate -> Call hierarchy

Eclipse CDT - Главное меню -> Navigate -> Open call hierarchy