# gКак определить, какая перегрузка функции вызывается?

Tags: c++, отладка, gcc, mingw, перегрузка-функций

Есть некий вызов библиотечной функции, для которой объявлено множество перегрузок и макросов в разных хедерах. IDE при переходе по вызову ведёт к макросу. Можно ли как-то заставить компилятор указать, какая в итоге **функция** вызывается? Типа опции компилятору, с помощью который покажется отладочная информация, указывающая конкретную функцию после всего препроцессинга, которая в месте вызова будет вызываться или встраиваться. В рантайме проверить затруднительно, т.к. 1) нельзя поставить точку останова на исходники библиотеки; 2) неясно, какой путь приводит к вызову этой функции.

К примеру:

```
// my_src.cpp
// ...many lines...
// lib::foo(implicitly_convertable_arg_1, ..., implicitly_convertable_arg_N);
// ...many lines...
//
// library.h
// ...many lines...
// #define foo foo_impl
// ...many lines...
// foo_impl(type_11 par_1, ..., type_1N par_N); (1)
// ...
// foo_impl(type_21 par_1, ..., type_NN par_N); (N)
```

Как узнать, какая из функций `[1; N]` вызывается? Надо для отладки.

Comment: *"нельзя поставить точку останова на исходники библиотеки"* На исходники нельзя, но по идее по названию функции должно быть можно.

Comment: Откомпилируйте в ассемблер. В ассемблере все перегрузки функций имеют разные имена. В вызывающем коде вы увидите конкретное имя. По имени восстановите перегрузку. См. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: @HolyBlackCat по названию = по сигнатуре? Если так, то мне её и надо выяснить, что не подходит (либо на все ставить, но тогда будет много ложных срабатываний). Если просто по имени, то это имя макроса и по идее не должно работать (я попробовал и не остановилось, хотя не уверен, что выполнил все необходимые действия)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, но файл большой очень, долго искать придётся, что к чему. Можно ли получить чисто список функций/вызовов без остального ассемблера?

Comment: Ничего не придётся искать. Декорированное имя содержит в себе имя функции. Код вызывающей функции вы легко отыщете по имени. Не вижу больших проблем.

Comment: Запуститесь в GDB (чуствую что сойдёт любой отладчик). Поставьте останов на вызов функции (в вашем коде, не библиотечном). Отобразите ассемблер. Прочитайте декорированное имя.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в рантайме gdb не знаю пути к этому вызову; я нашёл в дизассемблере функцию, которая содержит вызов искомой функции, теперь вручную можно найти её вызов, но долго; проблема не столько в декорировании, сколько в макросах; я не могу просто взять и сделать поиск подстроки, т.к. макросы произвольные имена имеют

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy похоже, что функция заинлайнилась, как быть тогда? хотя можно собирать с другим флагом, но долго опять таки

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я не знаю имя искомой функции из-за нескольких уровней макросов, я про это

Comment: Если функция встроилась, ставьте останов на этот адрес в ассемблере.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy кажется, нашёл замангленное имя. Как теперь узнать нормальное? https://demangler.com сайт не открывается у меня

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy всё, нашёл - `c++filt.exe`, спасибо за помощь

Comment: Для определения этого в рантайме достаточно сделать step into при вызове и сразу оказываешься в определении функции. Кроме того, выяснить, какая функция запускается можно и без запуска, зная перечень кандидатов и правила ранжирования перегруженных функций.

Comment: @user7860670 говорю же, это библиотечный вызов и исходников нет + даже прийти к нужному вызову затруднительно, т.к. не знаю сценарий, который приводит к конкретной строке кода

Comment: В начале вопроса же написано, что "для которой определено множество перегрузок и макросов в разных хедерах" - т.е. исходники у вас есть и второй способ сразу работает. "какой путь приводит к вызову этой функции" - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1397955/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/1397996#1397996